# What's a synonym for double-barrel descriptive word?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Two words with a new combined meaning can be  more descriptive than a single word.

These words can be joined using one of the following

- hyphen e.g pseudo-intellectual, double-barrel
- space
- no separator (i.e. conjoined)

What are such words called ?

Comment: Why do you not hyphenate *double-barrel*, or as I would have said *double-barrelled*? Surely that is an example of a double-barrelled adjective, isn't it? But I am unclear as to your question.

Comment: you are correct it needed a hyphen

Comment: @devc2 I've reworked you question a bit to hopefully make it clearer so it might be reopened. If my edit contradicts you intentions, please revert my changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Compound adjectives**
>
> Compound adjectives most commonly end in an adjective (e.g. homesick), or in an -ing or -ed adjective form (e.g. ground-breaking, short-sighted).
> — http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/compounds